# How to get Bundle product id using bundle item?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, bundled-product, bundle

I can get bundle item id, using that id I wants bundle product Id. 
I have used below code, but it is not working:

```
   $grouped_product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_bundle');
   $groupedParentIds = $grouped_product_model->getParentIdsByChild(#productid); //#productid will be bundle item id.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is working for me, There might be indexing issue, i didn't get value of group ids

```
  if($_product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE){
                $bundleed_product_model = Mage::getModel('bundle/product_type');
                $bundleedParentIds = $bundleed_product_model->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getId()); 

                if(sizeof($bundleedParentIds) >0){
                    foreach($bundleedParentIds as $bundleedParentId)
                    {
                        if(!in_array($bundleedParentId, $bundleProIds)) { 
                            $iCnt++;
                            $bundleProIds[]= $bundleedParentId; 
                            $bundleProducts[] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($bundleedParentId);
                        }
                        if($iCnt == 4){break;}
                    }
                }
            }
```

Above code will get bundle products array which have current product as a child.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
$bundleIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('bundle/selection')->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
```